# Impossibility to set new dbpath in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

Versions: 
Mongodb -> v5.0.9 
Ubuntu -> 18.04 64 bits with architecture x86_64

For some purposes I prefer to change the folder containing my database in MongoDB.

First I made the folder the property of the `mongodb` group: `sudo chgrp mongodb /newpath/mongodatabases` and it's alright, it did it:

```
avy@machine:~/newpath$ ls-l
drwxrwxrwx  2 avy mongodb  4096 juin  20 05:24  mongodatabases
```

Second I tried to set the new path by the book: `(base) avy@machine:~$ mongod --dbpath /newpath/mongodatabases`

but it gave me the following display with some errors:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.897+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.900+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.901+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.901+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.903+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.903+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.903+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.903+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.904+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":9691,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/newpath/mongodatabases","architecture":"64-bit","host":"machine"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.904+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.9","gitVersion":"6f7dae919422dcd7f4892c10ff20cdc721ad00e6","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.904+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.904+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/newpath/mongodatabases"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.905+02:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.905+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1019}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-20T05:56:54.905+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Considering the message `"msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"` I checked the ownership of the file `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` and it actually is owned by mongodb

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ ls -ls /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
0 srwx------ 1 mongodb mongodb 0 juin  20 05:50 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Besides `mongod` seems to have no problem to work itself:

```
(base) avy@machine:~$ sudo service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-06-20 05:50:00 CEST; 1s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 8980 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─8980 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

juin 20 05:50:00 avywam systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
```

What should I do to make it done ?

Comment: `Second I tried to set the new path by the book: (base) avy@machine:~$ mongod --dbpath /newpath/mongodatabases` This doesn't _set_ the new path, this runs the server using this new path. Change `/etc/mongod.conf` instead and restart the running server.

Comment: @tkausl well, I tried it multiple times but it didn't work at those times. I think after changing the ownership of the folder `/newpath/mongodatabases` it was the the thing I should do right after: "Change /etc/mongod.conf instead and restart the running server". Thanks.

Comment: You should stop the running mongod before you copy/move any data folder.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions below:

1. Access your running instance and shutdwon it if it is running:

   ```
     mongo --port 27017   
     use admin
     db.shutdownServer({force:true})
   ```
2. Check if the file exists still and if exists remove it via:

   ```
    rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
   ```

( Sometimes if the mongod process was not running , there is possible the mongod process didn't exited properly and sock file to be still there preventing the new instance to start. )

3. Start again your mongod service via: ( the dbPath need to be set to the new location before doing this )

   ```
    sudo service mongod start
   ```
4. Mark the answer as useful and  accepted so I get 25 points for the hint :)